# How to add a summary count to this query

Tags: postgresql, count, window-functions

I am using Postgres 9.4 and I have a query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT attendees.event_id, attendees.user_id, users.tags
FROM users, attendees
WHERE 'crystal:promo' = ANY(users.tags)
AND users.id = attendees.user_id
AND attendees.status = 'paid' 
GROUP BY attendees.event_id, attendees.user_id, users.tags
ORDER BY attendees.event_id desc;
```

Result:

```
 event_id | user_id | tags 
----------+---------+------
 1        | 2       | ...
 1        | 4       | ...
 1        | 7       | ...
```

I'd like to add a summary column for each row that is the total number of people per event independent of user tags such that the result would be something like:

```
select count(*) from attendees where status='paid' group by event_id
```

and joined with the above results (assuming 11 paid):

```
 event_id | user_id | tags | total_event_paid
----------+---------+------+------------------
 1        | 2       | ...  | 11
 1        | 4       | ...  | 11
 1        | 7       | ...  | 11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just replace `attendees` with a subquery that pre-selects "paid" rows and add the count without aggregating - with a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.event_id, a.user_id, u.tags, a.total_event_paid
FROM   users u
JOIN  (
   SELECT *, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY event_id) AS total_event_paid
   FROM   attendees
   WHERE  status = 'paid'
   ) a ON u.id = a.user_id
WHERE  'crystal:promo' = ANY(u.tags)
ORDER  BY a.event_id DESC;
```

`DISTINCT` (or `GROUP BY`) in the outer `SELECT` may or may not be needed.

Related:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tbl_count as (select event_id, count(*) as rec_count from attendees 
                    where status='paid' group by event_id),
tbl_main as (
SELECT attendees.event_id, attendees.user_id, users.tags
FROM users 
INNER JOIN attendees ON users.id = attendees.user_id
WHERE 
    'crystal:promo' = ANY(users.tags)
    and 
attendees.status = 'paid' 
GROUP BY attendees.event_id, attendees.user_id, users.tags ORDER BY attendees.event_id desc)

SELECT 
    tbl_main.event_id, 
    tbl_main.user_id, 
    tbl_main.tags,
    tbl_count.rec_count
FROM tbl_main
LEFT JOIN tbl_count ON tbl_count.event_id = tbl_main.event_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html) you could use window function with `FILTER`. Something like:

```
SELECT attendees.event_id, attendees.user_id, users.tags
,count(*) filter (where status = 'paid') over (partition by event_id) users_paid
FROM users, attendees
WHERE 'crystal:promo' = ANY(users.tags)
AND users.id = attendees.user_id
AND attendees.status = 'paid' 
GROUP BY attendees.event_id, attendees.user_id, users.tags
ORDER BY attendees.event_id desc;
```

Comment: You can't have `filter (where status = 'paid')` because `status` is not in the `group by` list.